# Adding a list of layers to a keras model computation graph (functional API)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

EDIT: More clarification -

I have a pre-trained model file which I can load and pull `model.layers` and `model.weights` from. This model may have a complex set of interconnected layers.

I want to be able to use the `model.layers` or the `model()` file directly to append it to a layer in another neural network.

```
#Dummy model - this function is not available to me; only the model file
def model1():
    inp = layers.Input((3,))
    x = layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(inp)
    out = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)    
    model = Model(inp, out)
    return model

pretrained_model = model1() #I have THIS only!

L = pretrained_model.layers
print(L)
```

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer at 0x7f915d6778b0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7f915d643790>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7f915e124e50>]
```

I want to take the Dense layers `L[1:]` and add them to another architecture (Not the weights, just the layers). Something like below as @Anton has described in his solution.

[image]

```
inp = layers.Input((3,))
x = Dense(3, activation='relu')(inp)
m0 = get_layers(pretrained_model)(x) #<---
out = layers.Dense(2)(m0)
```

This should give me a `model.summary()` with 5 layers - `inp, x, L[1], L[2], out`

But I am unable to use the list of layers directly.

**I can come up with a function that recreates a partial computation graph based on these layers but I am looking for something simpler.**

I have already tried modifying the model1() function to work for me as below, which serves my purpose but assuming I only get a model file and with a massive number of layers, this will not be possible.

```
def model1(layer):
    #inp = layers.Input((3,))
    x = layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(layer)
    out = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)    
    model = Model(inp, out)
    return model.output
```

Comment: If you want to plot all the layers like the image I attached, use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=True)`

Comment: yea that I have already thanks! It jsut shows the pre-trained model as a single functional layer.

Comment: even when using the `expand_nested=True` ?

Comment: OH I AM BLIND!, that worked! this is perfect thanks :))))

Comment: One question is there a way to rename the `m0 = pretrained_model(x)` functional layer?

Comment: Check if there is already a SO question/answer for that and if not write one.  I'll check your account in 30 min and if you post it as a question I'll take a look

Comment: sure thing, ill figure it out thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How can I use a model generator inside another model

We can use the generate `model1()` and replace

```
inp = layers.Input((3,))
x = Dense(3, activation='relu')(inp)
m0 = get_layers(pretrained_model)(x) # <---
out = layers.Dense(2)(m0)
```

with

```
inp = layers.Input((3,))
x = layers.Dense(3, activation='relu')(inp)
m0 = pretrained_model(x) # <---
out = layers.Dense(2)(m0)
```

and if we want a new model generator `model2()` that does that as a function

```
def model2(pretrained_model):
    inp = layers.Input((3,), name='model2_input')
    x = layers.Dense(3, activation='relu', name='model2_x')(inp)
    m0 = pretrained_model(x)
    out = layers.Dense(2, name='model2_out')(m0)
    model = Model(inp, out, name='model2')
    return model

second_model = model2()
```

If we look at the graph of `second_model` we can see that indeed it contains the layers of model1

[image: shape of the compute graph of the second model]

We can generate the above image using

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(second_model, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=True)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. As I mention, I CAN use these layers to generate a new computation graph for model 1. Then I can use these layers or add the model as you have. However, let's say I don't have the computation graph as a function. Instead, I only have a list of layers (`pretrained_model.layers`). What I am looking for is how to start that and then add that into an existing model 2. I dont want to generate a new computation graph, instead just use say `<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7f915d643790>` and add that in the middle of a computation graph. Thanks!

Comment: I've attempted to answer this and have updated the answer.  Look at the new section at the end.

Comment: Hi @Anton thanks for yet another response. I tried this method as well but it doesn't work for me. Here is the reason why - Imagine I have a large pretrained model which is not a sequential model and has some complex set of interconnected layers. Using the layer-wise addition method, I would never be able to recreate that structure until I have a complete detailed architecture design of the pretrained model with me. This means I would have to pretty much reconstruct the whole model as part of my new model.

Comment: The goal here, as I described is to embed a pretrained model (blackbox where I know the input and output dimensions) as part of a new model. I only have access to the methods that can be used on the pretrained model (model.layers, model.weights)

Comment: How do you imagine specifying the subgraph part of model1 that you want?

Comment: So model1() is a blackbox to me. I only know the input, output, layers and weights (like any pretrained model that I can download from the web). Since I do know the input and output, I should be able to connect a suitable computation subgraph  to the input and take a new computation subgraph from its output. `mylayers->blackbox->mylayers`. The issue here is, I dont want to sit and recreate each layer from the model1() because in most cases its a blackbox to me.

Comment: you want all the layers, in the structure of the old model, right from the input to the output, but pretrained (i.e. all the weights reset to initialization values) ?

Comment: I dont want to worry about the weights at this point, I might choose to re-initialize the or initialize them from the current state or fix them completely. Basically, I am looking to build a TensorFlow computation graph where, between 2 intermediate layers I can embed another model (of which I only have the model file). Weights initialization maybe be a much more complex problem to solve that I will look into after this, however, for now, Ill take whichever of the 2 I can get - re-initialize or initialize from current weights but trainable.

Comment: `input->layer1->layer2->pretrained_model->layer3->layer4->output`..... If I want to make the pretrained model weights fixed, then Ill just set the layers to not be trainable. If i want to continue training them, ill just keep them as is and train further epochs. And if I want to reset them, ill initialize the model.weights() as random values from a distribution.

Comment: The example I gave is what you ask.  In the example I gave that generates model2 and uses model1, model1 could be ResNet, or BERT, or anything so long as the inputs and outputs match.

Comment: Oh, which example are you referring to? Could you clarify, you actually gave me a lot of methods to attempt the solution :)

Comment: I've updated the solution to be a minimum solution with no distractions

Comment: This actually does more or less solve my question so I have marked it as the right one. I do with that instead of a `functional layer`, I could actually get the model architecture displayed as part of the summary for model2. Nonetheless, it works! thanks!